# How to fix objects in the indoor environment with ArCore?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I need to insert some virtual objects in an indoor environment, but I need the position of these objects to be fixed. I have already tried using markers with the vuforia but it is complicated, it takes time to recognize. I'm thinking of using Google's ArCore. Does anyone know if this is possible and, if so, do they know how to do it? 
I'm using Unity to do this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you checked `HelloAR` example from ARCore?

Comment: Yes, but I need to put different objects in fixed positions. ARCore's HelloAR only shows how to use the Android system character, which appears every time the screen is played. This hinders the test I need to do because I want to position different objects at fixed points.

Comment: You can use ´Session.CreateAnchor´ and put objects at arbitrary positions if that is what you want. You do not need a plane or marker with that one.

Answer (score 0):

ARCore places the camera relative to the detected plane, so you will need a plane at some point so the application can locate the camera into the game.

HelloAR shows how this works, you may test into the unity editor and see how the camera moves arround the points and the detected plane.

One solution for your problem may be the image detection of ARCore + Plane detection, you place the image on the floor and when the image is detected you will have your objects in place while you move arround, but you will need to have a plane to move, not only the image detection, because if you don't, you will lose the objects once the camera loses the image.